# Should I replace/repair the exterior trim or just replace the entire window and exterior trim?

Tags: windows, exterior, trim, window-frame, trim-carpentry

Just took the plunge into homeownership and bought a cozy Cape Cod style home from 1985. Loving the wooden double-pane windows, but some seals are worn.The exterior's wooden trim needs a refresh. Wondering if I should replace both the windows and trim or just the trim in the 11 windows on the first floor as the 2nd floor windows don't have these trim and appear to be in good condition.  Should I stick with wood or switch to PVC or aluminum? Seeking advice on durability and aesthetics! Thanks in advance!

https://www.gocanvas.com/values/19131422816

https://www.gocanvas.com/values/19131422780

https://www.gocanvas.com/values/19131422777

https://www.gocanvas.com/values/19131422773

Comment: Adding trim over the wood will be much cheaper than replacing windows, a few hundred compare to thousands.  Unless the windows are old single pane just a tiny step up from a hole in the wall.  Doing the trim and making sure of the sealing around the windows should only cost the price of one window..

Comment: You should probably edit out the pricing part, as that’s off topic here. (Take the tour.)

Comment: Check with the locals because there could be some restrictions on what you can do.